Why doesn't Brave show up when I launch it?
LXQT on clean install of Spiral Linux. OpenBox is the WM. I installed the Brave web browser using instructions on its web site. When I launch the app from the LXQT menu, Brave's windows do not appear, but I can see its processes running:
$ ps -fC brave
  PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
will      268820  268814  0 10:17 ?        00:00:00 /opt/brave.com/brave/brave
will      268830  268820  0 10:17 ?        00:00:00 /opt/brave.com/brave/brave --type=zygote --no-zygote-sandbox --string-annotations --crashpad-handler-pid=268822 --enable-crash-reporter=, --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable
will      268831  268820  0 10:17 ?        00:00:00 /opt/brave.com/brave/brave --type=zygote --string-annotations --crashpad-handler-pid=268822 --enable-crash-reporter=, --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable
will      268833  268831  0 10:17 ?        00:00:00 /opt/brave.com/brave/brave --type=zygote --string-annotations --crashpad-handler-pid=268822 --enable-crash-reporter=, --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable

I use a laptop with a second monitor, but I've checked both displays.
I've checked OpenBox Configuration Settings, and only two desktops are configured. I've checked both while Brave is running.
$ inxi -Sx
System:
  Host: will-hp-pavillion-17 Kernel: 6.10.6+bpo-amd64 arch: x86_64 bits: 64
    compiler: N/A Desktop: LXQt v: 1.2.1 Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm

Launching Brave from the command line:
$ brave-browser
Gtk-Message: 08:47:50.580: Failed to load module "colorreload-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 08:47:50.580: Failed to load module "window-decorations-gtk-module"
[333251:333251:1007/084750.651308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(279)] GLib-GObject: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed
[333251:333251:1007/084750.651353:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(279)] GLib-GObject: g_type_interface_add_prerequisite: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INTERFACE (interface_type)' failed
[333251:333251:1007/084750.651361:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(279)] GLib: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
[333251:333251:1007/084750.651367:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(279)] GLib-GObject: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed
[333251:333251:1007/084750.651372:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(279)] GLib-GObject: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed

Could this be a permissions issue?  Thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Try running brave from a terminal. Do you get any error messages?

@terdon: updated my question with this output.  Thanks!
